# How to read a appended log file from current date using batch script

Tags: windows

My requiremnet is I have a sample appened log file shown below and  I need to find 2 phrases "Total Records with errors= 0" & Batch filter ended for the current date and if it finds then exit the job succussfully if doesn't found those 2 phrases for current date need to copy those phrases in a .txt file and exit the job

c:\>date /t 
Wed 03/25/2015

### Batch Summary

Total Records with Errors= 0
Batch Filter Ended

c:\>date /t 
Thu 3/26/2015

### Batch Summary

Total Records with Errors= 0
Batch Filter Ended

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could simple use a pipe for realize the AND operator.

```
 rem define mydate

For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a/%%b/%%c)

find /c %mydate% C:\MyFiles\*.txt | find /c "Total Records with errors= 0"
```

From your comment, you need an OR operator

In this case I would do the search with findstr and the counting with find /c

```
findstr /c:"03/25/2015" /c:"Total Records with errors= 0" C:\MyFiles\*.txt | find /c /v ""
```

Comment: But the date changes everyday so  I can't hard code the date. is there any way to get the current date in this appened file readfrom that and pick the phrases what i need

Comment: So the above logic will give the phrases what Iam looking for current date right even though my log file appends every day with date and also and this works for single file or can I do it for multiple appened file how can I handle that?

Comment: @KalyanKraleti this code read all txt file in Mayflies directory.

Comment: Thanks Eric  I new to this scripting Sorry for asking more questions. So the code checks for current and the phrases if either of them missing it will fail right or  do i need to handle anything like you said OR operator or AND operator which one needs to be handled

Comment: for /f "tokens=1 delims=. " %%a in ("%reqfilenamelist%") do set partialresultflnm=%%a

Comment: I am trying to paste my code here in bits and pieces to so that you can get an Idea is there any other way i can post it so that you have better understanding

Comment: //FOR /F "eol=, tokens=1 delims=, " %%i in (%batchloghome%\%reqfilenamelist%) do (
//color a 
//@echo %%i 
//@set logfilename=%%i

Comment: type "%batchloghome%\%%i" | find /c %mydate% | find /c "Total Records with Errors= 0"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call :NotOkay1
//type "%batchloghome%\%%i" | find /c %mydate% | find /c "Batch Filter Ended"
//IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call :NotOkay2
//IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 call :Okay  
//)

Comment: I have pasted my logic here see if you can can understand what I am trying to do makes any sense

Comment: in batch file use the call label with param  **call :findDate %%A** and create label line for traitement **:findDate**

    `for /f "tokens=1 delims=. " %%a in ("%reqfilenamelist%") do call :findDate %%A

    ENDLOCAL

    :findDate
    find /c %mydate% %1 | find /c "Total Records with errors= 0"
    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call :NotOkay2 
    IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 call :Okay 
    ENDLOCAL

    :NotOkay2

    :Okey`

Comment: I am little confused I have to screen the remainign  all log files so how do I put the path here

Comment: type ""%batchloghome%\%%i" ENDLOCAL :findDate find /c %mydate% %1 | find /c "Total Records with errors= 0"    how do I pass the path and file name so it will do the forloop for all the files present in that   eqfilenamelist variable

Comment: FOR /F "eol=, tokens=1 delims=, " %%i in (%batchloghome%\%reqfilenamelist%) do (
color a
@set logfilename=%%i

Comment: color b
ENDLOCAL :findDate find /c %mydate% %1 | find /c "Total Records with Errors= 0"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call :NotOkay1
ENDLOCAL :findDate find /c %mydate% %1 | find /c "Batch Filter Ended"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 call :NotOkay2
IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 call :Okay  ENDLOCAL :NotOkay1 :Okay
ENDLOCAL :NotOkay1 :Okay
ENDLCOAL :NotOkay2 :Okay

Comment: does this makes sense. I need to check two phrases